# Unable to download project from Bitbucket in Eclipse getting 'Transport Error'

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have tried some approach then also it is not resolving 'transport error'.

I have set `http.sslverify=false`, not working.
I have removed `.eclipse` folder from Users/myuser, not working.

[image]

Comment: I don't know Eclipse specific error but I will suggest first copy url and open in browser to make sure url is correct.

Comment: Did you have a proxy setup in eclipse and verified your bitbucket connection by checking out project using git console